# How to ignore a group of characters until meets a specified character in regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've following regular expression which I need to match using `re.match`. I first need to match 'susa' and ignore anything up to '@' symbol (not including it) and capture everything after it. However, when I try to get the output using `re.search`, it doesn't match. Why don't I get desired output? Does `re.match` actually matches the output? (I cannot check since it only gives the memory location). Thanks.

```
import re

output = 'susa ssh://user@internal.website.ide.company.uk/du33/abo33/ohs231/stk/projects/project1/'
url_match = re.match("\s*susa\s+[^(/.+?(?=@)/)]+([^ ]+)", output)

Result = re.search("\s*susa\s+[^(/.+?(?=@)/)]+([^ ]+)", output)

if Result:
    print Result.groups()

In [29]: runfile('/home/user/Desktop/python_practise/match_urls.py', wdir='/home/user/Desktop/python_practise')
    ('//user@internal.website.ide.company.uk/du33/abo33/ohs231/stk/projects/project1/',)
```

Comment: `re.match` as `re.search` yields the match data object and the value matched is in `Result.group()` and the Group 1 value is in `Result.group(1)`

Comment: Your regex is malformed as `[^(/.+?(?=@)/)]` is a negated character class matching any char other than the ones in the class.

Comment: Why not use `split('@') ? Can even split on space first and/or see if it starts with 'susa' or not. Seems overly complex to use regex for this.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/5q5oqJ, is it working as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, it does. Thanks! But can we capture the part 'susa' too?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
r"\s*susa\s[^@]+(\S+)"
```

**Details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `susa` - a `susa` substring
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[^@]+` - 1+ chars other than `@` (`[^...]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any chars other than those specified in the class)
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars.

To get the value inside Group 1, use `url_match.group(1)`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5q5oqJ):

```
import re

output = 'susa ssh://user@internal.website.ide.company.uk/du33/abo33/ohs231/stk/projects/project1/'
url_match = re.match(r"\s*susa\s[^@]+(\S+)", output)
if url_match:
    print(url_match.group(1))
# => @internal.website.ide.company.uk/du33/abo33/ohs231/stk/projects/project1/

Result = re.search(r"\s*susa\s[^@]+(\S+)", output)
if Result:
    print(Result.group(1))
# => @internal.website.ide.company.uk/du33/abo33/ohs231/stk/projects/project1/
```